# how to next new sceen and hold nav title in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new member in ionic and I want create a simple app with menu sidebar left and in fist page I have a list item, when I click item on list I will show new sceen detail item, but I want hold navigation bar in top. Here is my sceen app I want create.
I created a menu sidebar and list item same left picture but when I set event ng-click for item in list I can't create new page same right picture.
How I can hold navigationbar and change content to new page?

[image]

Here is my code:
menu.html:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">

        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"  ></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left" width="{{dev_width}}">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
     <div class="bar-header">
     </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    
 <ion-content class="custom">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/menu/groupa">
         <img src="{{availableImages[0].src}}" />{{availableImages[0].text}} 
        </ion-item>
       <ion-item menu-close href="#/menu/groupb">
         <img src="{{availableImages[1].src}}" />{{availableImages[1].text}} 
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/menu/groupc">
         <img src="{{availableImages[1].src}}"/>{{availableImages[0].text}} 
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/login">
         Logout 
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
 
 <ion-footer-bar >
  <span class="color-title" ><img  src="{{availableImages[2].src}}" width="30" style="vertical-align:middle ;margin-right:15px"/>{{availableImages[2].text}} </span>
 </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Groupb.html:

```html
<ion-view  align-title="center">
 <ion-nav-title>
  <span class="color-title">Group B</span>
 </ion-nav-title>
 <ion-content  class="list-groupa">
<div ng-show="isLoading">Loading.....</div>
    
    <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="employee in datashow" type="item-text-wrap"  ng-click="clicker(datashow)">
                <span class="item-group"><b>{{employee.Type}}</b></span>
                <p><span class="item-group">test desc2 {{employee.Distance.Value}}</span></p>
               
            </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
<!-- </view> -->
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

```js
$scope.clicker = function(myValue){
        $scope.dataToShare = myValue;
     srvShareData.setData($scope.dataToShare);
     $state.go('detailgroupb');
   };
```

Detailgroupb.html

```html
<ion-view  align-title="center">
   <ion-nav-bar >
   <button ng-click="goBack()">
      Set title to banana!
    </button>
</ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content  class="list-groupa">
    <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="employee in sharedData" type="item-text-wrap"  ng-click="clicker(employee)">
            <!-- href="#/employee/{{employee.id}}" -->
                <span class="item-group"><b>{{employee.Type}}</b></span>
                <p><span class="item-group">test desc2 {{employee.Distance.Value}}</span></p>
               
            </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```html
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider
  .state('login',{
   url:'/login',
   templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
   controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  
  .state('menu',{
   url:'/menu',
   templateUrl:'templates/menu.html',
   controller:'MenuCtrl'
  })
  
  .state('menu.groupa', {
   url: '/groupa',
   views: {
     'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/groupa.html',
    controller:'GroupaCtrl'
     }
   }
    })
  .state('menu.groupc', {
   url: '/groupc',
   views: {
     'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/groupc.html',
    controller:'GroupcCtrl'
     }
   }
    })
  .state('menu.groupb', {
   url: '/groupb',
   views: {
     'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/groupb.html',
    controller:'GroupbCtrl'
     }
   }
    })
    .state('detailgroupb',{
   url:'/detailgroupb',
   templateUrl:'templates/detailgroupb.html',
   controller:'GroupbDetailCtrl'
   
  })
    ;
  
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
})
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {

  // note that you can also chain configs
  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
});
```

My result:
[image]

Comment: What does your (relevant) html look like? What have you tried?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/

Comment: @lakshay I created a menu side and list item in page but when I click and used ng-click and $state.go() it create new page but in new page I have not menu side bar.

Comment: I think it'll be better if you could post some of your code

Comment: @lakshay I added it. can you help me?

Comment: ok....so now with the current code how is your view coming......

Comment: @lakshay I added my result

Comment: try by removing the whole <ion-nav-bar>....<ion-nav-bar> tag in Detailgroupb.html

Comment: no ,it will only show list. I was thinking to create a directive toolbar and add in detailgroub.html.

Comment: i tried running the html in detailgroub.html without those tags and it run fine for me.

Comment: yep, it run fine. but you can see in top page it have not toolbar navigation